# QGIS shapefiles to a Magellan GPS

Tags: qgis, gps, gpx

I've got some shapefiles that I want to be able to turn into maps on a hand held GPS (Magellan Explorist 350H). So far I've had no success trying to convert the files to gpx and upload that way. I've also tried some free software DNRgps and ITN converter. The latter allowed me to convert a file to a "Magellan SD" file type (sort of; it split the file into a bunch of sections, so I would have to convert each section, and who knows how that would turn out on the actual GPS), but then I could not figure out how to get it onto the GPS.

It seems like this should be a straight forward thing to do. My searching around on the internet has not provided any straight forward answers. Hopefully someone on here can help.

I am able to convert the files to gpx, however they are not in a usable form. The gpx breaks down the shapefile into a bunch of different routes. If I force it to track it breaks it down into a bunch of little tracks. These aren't really helpful since what I'm trying to convert is some shapefiles of roads. After converting them to gpx I was having trouble uploading them to the Magellan device. The Magellan software VantagePoint doesn't recognize the tracks or routes as having any content.

Comment: Where do you run into problems in the process of converting to gpx and uploading? Are you succeeding at converting the files to gpx? Can you upload any gpx file?

Comment: I am able to convert the files to gpx, however they are not in a usable form. The gpx breaks down the shapefile into a bunch of different routes. If I force it to track it breaks it down into a bunch of little tracks. These aren't really helpful since waht I'm trying to convert is some shapefiles of roads. After converting them to gpx I was having trouble uploading them to the Magellan device. The Magellan software VantagePoint doesn't recognize the tracks or routes as having any content.